# Thread Building Blocks concurrent_bounded_queue — how do I «close» it?

Tags: multithreading, queue, tbb

I am using `concurrent_bounded_queue` Intel TBB 4.1 Update 3 for communication between producer and consumer threads:

- [concurrent_queue](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm)
- [concurrent_bounded_queue](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm)

The queue class has a method called `abort` which throws `tbb::user_abort` to all threads which block on `pop` and `push` of the queue instance.  The communication between two threads may look like this:

```
ConsThread | ProdThread
-----------+-------------
q.pop      |  get new data
(wait)     |  q.push
process    |  get new data
q.pop      |  no more data!
(wait)     |  q.abort
quit       |  quit
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use it to reliably shut down the queue even in this simple example, because if some of the consumers are not done processing previously `pop`ped data before the call to `abort`, they will finish the iteration and return to blocking on `pop`:

```
ConsThread | ProdThread
-----------+-------------
q.pop      |  get new data
(wait)     |  q.push
process    |  get new data
process    |  no more data!
process    |  q.abort
process    |  quit
process    |
q.pop      |
(wait)     |
(wait)     |
(wait)     |
(so lonely)|
```

Right now I am employing a moderately disgusting hack that spawns another non-detached thread (which joins the consumer pool threads) and waits for it to finish while sending more `abort`s from time to time for the late comers:

```
bool areConsumerThreadsJoinedThankYou = false;
std::thread joiner(Joiner(consumerPool, &areConsumerThreadsJoinedThankYou));

while (!areConsumerThreadsJoinedThankYou) {
    rawQueue.abort();
    MAGIC_MSLEEP(100);
}
```

`class Joiner`'s implementation is pretty much

```
void Joiner::operator()(void)
{
    for (auto it = this->m_threadPool.begin();
         it < this->m_threadPool.end();
         it++)
        (*it)->join();
    this->m_done = true;
    *(this->m_flag) = true;
}
```

This of course is very ugly.  Is there a more fundamental solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a designated "EndOfData" item.  If you know you have K consumers, have the producer push K "EndOfData" items after it is done pushing data items.  Have each consumer quit after it pops a "EndOfData" item.

If K is not known in advance, have the producer push a single "EndOfData" item.  Then have each consumer who pops an "EndOfData" item push another "EndOfData" item before leaving.  After all consumers are done, there will be a single "EndOfData" item remaining, which will be destroyed when the queue is destroyed.

Comment: Well, since this comes from the architect of TBB, I guess there is no better way :)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.  Indeed I was the architect for TBB, though Alexey Kukanov has since taken on the role of TBB architect.