# How to use TBB's concurrent_bounded_concurrent_queue abort correctly?

Tags: c++, concurrency, tbb

Suppose, we have a typical queue consumer loop with a stop flag:

```
class consumer {
    atomic<bool> keep_running;
    concurrent_bounded_queue queue;

    void loop() {
        while (keep_running)
            // <- danger zone
            queue.pop();
    }

    void stop() {
        keep_running = false;
        queue.abort();
    }
};
```

If used as written, `stop` will fail when called after the `keep_running` check but before the `pop` call since `abort` only terminates `pop` calls already in progress.

We also can't use a mutex to make sure the check and the `pop` are performed atomically, since then we would not be able to call `abort` while `pop` is in progress.

What is the correct usage here?

Comment: 'loop', not 'stop will fail' i suppose?

Comment: @anton, `stop` won't terminate the loop, and the loop will potentially hang.

Comment: Alexey, be more specific then please, i guess 'fail' means fail to achieve the goal but not any segfault or hang of the stop function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread Building Blocks concurrent\_bounded\_queue — how do I «close» it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961990/thread-building-blocks-concurrent-bounded-queue-how-do-i-close-it)